Проблема с расширением ipython для vscode
Очередные проблемы с ipython в vscode. Открыл я проект с которым ранее работал в pycharm, запускаю скрипт а мне надпись  консоле
ipython --no-autoindent --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="%load_ext autoreload" --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="%autoreload 2"
.venv➜  my ipython --no-autoindent --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="%load_ext autoreload" --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="%autoreload 
2"
zsh: command not found: ipython
.venv➜  my git:(b) ✗ %run "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/myPoker/main.py"
fg: job not found: run

Не понимаю что это значит и что от меня хотят. Помогите разобраться или лучше раскажите как работать с пайтон в этом самом vscode что б было максимально приближено к pycharm, расширения какие-то или еще что, а то весь уже измучился с этим vscode, но pycharm очень долго грузит и посоветовали vscode, решил попробовать и страдаю.

Сообщение zsh: command not found: ipython указывает на то, что VSCode не может найти команду ipython, вероятно, потому что он не установлен или не находится в вашем PATH.
Убедитесь, что IPython установлен. Вы можете установить его с помощью pip. Откройте терминал и выполните:
pip install ipython

